# Ways to become dazzled

Tags: pathfinder-2e, conditions, stealth, sneak-attack

The [Dazzled Condition](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=7) is quite useful for my rogue since if a creature is dazzled I am [concealed](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=4). So I can make a [Hide Action](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=62) to become [Hidden](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=22) and so I can make a [Sneak Attack](https://pathfinder2.dragonlash.com/classes/rogue/rogue-class-features/sneak-attack/). My question would be what ways does Pathfinder 2e provide to make someone dazzled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## There are a lot of ways

Just searching "[dazzled](https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?Query=dazzled&Filter=111111111111111&AllTerms=True&ExcludeAPModule=false&PFSLegalOnly=false)" on Archives of Nethys and looking at Feats, Spells, and Equipment shows that there are a plethora of ways to cause the Condition... but none of the Feats are available to Rogues by default so you'd have to consider other options. For instance, you could see if the Firework Technician Dedication is available (to be taken in place of Class Feats) or the Snare Crafter Dedication to learn Dust Pod and Mirror-Ball Snares (and place them quickly).

The only easily accessed item that causes Dazzled reliably seems to be Bismuth Leopard [Wondrous Figurines](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=270), until the DC 24 Will Save becomes easy to pass.

---

The best ways to cause dazzled are all spells, so you would probably have an easier time requesting allies' help in causing your enemies to be afflicted (assuming you are not a spellcasting rogue, in which case definitely check the Spells section of that search for options like Color Spray and Glitterdust).

Answer (score 3):

You could take the Beast Master Archetype dedication as early as level 2, choose the [bird animal companion](https://2e.aonprd.com/AnimalCompanions.aspx?ID=3), then for one action you can command it to fly into position and use its support benefit. If you land a strike your enemy will now be dazzled until it removes the persistent bleed damage. With the bird's 60ft fly speed, it should be able to get in position pretty easily.

If the bird's low ancestry hit points seem concerning, note that the [animal companions hit points](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=151) include 6 plus its con modifier for every level you have.

I haven't actually used this in a campaign yet, but I plan on doing so soon!